# How to have text fields fill 100% horizontally

Tags: java, eclipse, swt

If I have a text field with SWT, how can I get the field to fill to 100% or some specified width.

For example, this text field will only reach for so much horizontally.

```
public class Tmp {
    public static void main (String [] args) {
        Display display = new Display ();
        Shell shell = new Shell (display);
        GridLayout gridLayout = new GridLayout ();
        shell.setLayout (gridLayout);

        Button button0 = new Button(shell, SWT.PUSH);
        button0.setText ("button0");

        Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER | SWT.FILL);
        text.setText ("Text Field");

        shell.setSize(500, 400);
        //shell.pack();
        shell.open();

        while (!shell.isDisposed ()) {
            if (!display.readAndDispatch ())
                display.sleep ();
        }
        display.dispose ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make something like this:

```
Text text = new Text(shell, SWT.BORDER);
text.setText ("Text Field");
text.setLayoutData(new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER));
```

/: Since this is the accepted answer I remove the errors. Thx for correcting me.

Comment: Constructor GridData(int) is deprecated.

Use "new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.CENTER)" instead

Comment: You should not reuse GridData objects since they act as caches for grid cell calculations. GridData reuse can lead to layout bugs where several components sharing a common GridData are truncated to the size of the most small-size one. This is in the GridData's javadoc.

Comment: This seems wrong now (maybe the API has changed?), the [constructor `GridData(int width, int height)`](http://help.eclipse.org/juno/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fapi%2Forg%2Feclipse%2Fswt%2Flayout%2FGridData.html) sets minimum dimensions and can't be used with these SWT constants.

Answer (score 5):

Positioning of elements in a Component depends on the Layout object that you are using.  In the sample provided, you are using a GridLayout.  That means, that you need to provide a specific LayoutData object to indicate how you want your component displayed.  In the case of GridLayout, the object is GridData.

To achieve what you want, you must create a GridData object that grabs all horizontal space and fills it:

```
// Fills available horizontal and vertical space, grabs horizontal space,grab
// does not  grab vertical space
GridData gd = new GridData(SWT.FILL, SWT.FILL, true, false);
text.setLayoutData(gd);
```

Alternative ways include using a different LayoutManager, such as FormLayout.  This layout uses a FormData object that also allows you to specify how the component will be placed on the screen.

[You can also read this article on Layouts to understand how Layouts work](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Understanding-Layouts/index.html).

As a side note, the constructor new GridData(int style) is marked as "not recommended" in the documentation.  The explicit constructor shown in this example is preferred instead.